# Why is my MyClass.h/.m not linking with MyClassMain.m?

Tags: objective-c, linker

I attempt to compile in Terminal with the following:

```
$ clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation MyClassMain.m -o mc
```

Here's MyClassMain.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {  
        MyClass* mcObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        NSLog (@"%@", [mcObj triple]);
        NSLog (@"MyClass main");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error in terminal:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyClassMain-MV6Oew.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Apparently, MyClass.h/.m are not found. But these are saved in the same directory as MyClassMain.m (if that's even relevant). Can anyone suggest where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
`clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation MyClass.m MyClassMain.m -o mc`

you need to compile MyClass.m too in order for the `_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass` symbol to exist.